# Ckeditor padding does not work

Tags: coldfusion, ckeditor

This is an extension of [Textarea stripping html off in CKeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610153/textarea-losing-styles-in-email-coldfusion). I have  `<td align="left" style="padding:10px 40px 40px 40px">` in the body of the email the padding gets stripped off when the email is sent, (I see it in the source of the email). Any idea how to preserve the padding on the content in Ckeditor.

Comment: Is the whole style attribute eliminated?

Comment: Yes, its stripped off and many other styles. On the body !

Comment: OK I tried style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px; margin-right:40px;margin-left:40px;" this gets stripped as well by the CKEditor.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are using ACF but if you do then have you tried `var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('your_editor_id', { extraAllowedContent : 'td{*}' });` ? This code should allow all styles for `td` element.